# Multiplying table by using two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a multiplication table from 1 to 10 by using two dimensional arrays. When I run the program I get each value under each other, not a table. I get the first value as 1 and all others 0. I also get the error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at summing.main(summing.java:46)
Could you give some tips about the algorithm?

```
public static void main( String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);
    int x,y,z;
    int[][] table = new int[11][11];
    table[0][0] = 0;
    table[0][1] = 1;
    table[0][2] = 2;
    table[0][3] = 3;
    table[0][4] = 4;
    table[0][5] = 5;
    table[0][6] = 6;
    table[0][7] = 7;
    table[0][8] = 8;
    table[0][9] = 9;;
    table[0][10] = 10;  
    table[1][0] = 1;
    table[2][0] = 2;
    table[3][0] = 3;
    table[4][0] = 4;
    table[5][0] = 5;
    table[6][0] = 6;
    table[7][0] = 7;
    table[8][0] = 8;    
    table[9][0] = 9;
    table[10][0] = 10;

    System.out.println( "Start of multiplication\n");

    for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y <= 10; y++)
        {
            table[x][y] = table[x][1] * table[y][1];
            System.out.println(table[x][y]);//This line has the error.
        }
        table[x][y] = table[x][1] * table[y][1];
        System.out.print(table[x][y]);  
    }

    System.out.println( "\nEnd of multiplication\n" );
}
```

Comment: which line is summing.java:46?

Comment: btw when you exit the for loop using y iterator, y is 11, which is probably causing the out of bounds error

Comment: (a) Your calculation is overwriting the header row and column (b) The header row/column has index 0, not 1

Comment: Pretty sure you've identified the wrong line as the one with the error. I suspect it's the one just **after** the `for` loop over `y`, not the one inside.

Comment: No that's the correct line

Comment: @harold_finch: No, it's not. At that point, `x` and `y` are clearly in-bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, if you cannot get the error in your code. But first try to find the solution using your code as @T.J. Crowder said:

```
public static void main( String[] args) 
{
   // Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);
    int x,y;
    int[][] table = new int[11][11];
    table[0][0] = 0;
    table[0][1] = 1;
    table[0][2] = 2;
    table[0][3] = 3;
    table[0][4] = 4;
    table[0][5] = 5;
    table[0][6] = 6;
    table[0][7] = 7;
    table[0][8] = 8;
    table[0][9] = 9;;
    table[0][10] = 10;  
    table[1][0] = 1;
    table[2][0] = 2;
    table[3][0] = 3;
    table[4][0] = 4;
    table[5][0] = 5;
    table[6][0] = 6;
    table[7][0] = 7;
    table[8][0] = 8;    
    table[9][0] = 9;
    table[10][0] = 10;

    int[][] output_table = new int[11][11];

    System.out.println( "Start of multiplication\n");

    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        System.out.println("Table of: "+table[x][0]);
        for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            output_table[x][y] = table[0][x] * table[y][0];
            System.out.print(output_table[x][y]+"\t");//This line has the error.
        }

        output_table[x][y] = table[0][x] * table[y][0];
        System.out.println(output_table[x][y]);  
    }

    System.out.println( "\nEnd of multiplication\n" );
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see a series of lines rather than values across is that your inner `for` loop uses `println`, not `print`. The inner loop would use `print`, then the outer loop would use `println` to break lines.

The reason you get an out-of-bounds exception is because of this:

```
for (y = 0; y <= 10; y++)
{
    table[x][y] = table[x][1] * table[y][1];
    System.out.println(table[x][y]);
}
table[x][y] = table[x][1] * table[y][1]; // <======= Here
```

After the loop, `y` has the value `11`, so indexing into the table with it will cause the out-of-bounds exception. You don't want that line at all, or the one after it. After the inner loop, all you want is:

```
System.out.println();
```

...to start a new line.

Re algorithm: You don't actually *need* a two-dimensional array (or any array at all) to do this. But if you use one, you don't need to pre-initialize it with anything, because you have `x` and `y`. Just assign the product of `x` and `y` to the relevant cell in the inner loop:

```
table[x][y] = x * y;
```

> I am trying to make a multiplication table from 1 to 10...

Then the bounds of your loops are wrong, as you're going from ***0*** to 10 (inclusive). Instead, you'd want 0 (inclusive) to 10 (exclusive) and to add one to your `x` and `y` when doing the multiplication:

```
int[][] table = new int[10][10];
// ...
for (x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
    for (y = 0; y < 10; ++y) {
         // ...
        table[x][y] = (x + 1) * (y + 1);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that's enough to go on, I didn't want to actually write the code for you, as you'll learn more by working it out.

Comment: When I wrote  for (y = 0; y <= 9; y++)  it gives the same error.

Comment: @harold_finch: That suggests you were running old code. But please do read above, just changing one thing won't fix everything. I've given you several things to look at above, but fundamentally, you have to do the work, use the debugger to figure out what's going wrong, etc. That's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

First if all there is no need to start the loop from x=0 and y=0.
Second print all the values after calculating the values in the table
Third ArrayIndexOutOfBound was Because when the y loop completed the value of y is 11 and you were using the that value of y after the loop has finished.

```
public static void main( String[] args) 
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);
int x,y,z;
int[][] table = new int[11][11];
table[0][0] = 1;
table[0][1] = 1;
table[0][2] = 2;
table[0][3] = 3;
table[0][4] = 4;
table[0][5] = 5;
table[0][6] = 6;
table[0][7] = 7;
table[0][8] = 8;
table[0][9] = 9;;
table[0][10] = 10;  
table[1][0] = 1;
table[2][0] = 2;
table[3][0] = 3;
table[4][0] = 4;
table[5][0] = 5;
table[6][0] = 6;
table[7][0] = 7;
table[8][0] = 8;    
table[9][0] = 9;
table[10][0] = 10;

System.out.println( "Start of multiplication\n");

for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
{
    for (y = 1; y <= 10; y++)
    {
        table[x][y] = table[x][0] * table[y][0];

    }
}

System.out.println();

for(x=1;x<=10;x++){
    for(y=1;y<=10;y++){
        System.out.print(table[x][y] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

System.out.println( "\nEnd of multiplication\n" );
}
```

Comment: Code is correct but there is unnecessary output before the table

Comment: Fixed . just had to remove one println statement

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0;i<11;i++){
table[0][i] = i+1;
    table [i] [0] = i+1;
}
```

is much more efficient than having that massive list of declarations